# AWS Polling Scaling Group During Boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I'm trying to poll the current members of an AWS Scaling Group so that I can increment a value within my code. I need to be able to assign worker processes based on the number of active members. I've created a script that is running under rc.local on a new scaling group member:

```
for ((i=0; i<20; i++)); do
     OUT=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --query AutoScalingInstances[].InstanceId | wc -l)
     echo "Output is $OUT" >> /tmp/ec2log
     echo "Waiting for a response...." >> /tmp/ec2log
     ping -c 5 127.0.0.1 &> /dev/null  # Wait for a bit before retrying
done
```

My problem (and the reason why I'm looping over the command) is that the AWS CLI doesn't seem to respond to my initial requests.

**How can I pass the current number of servers in my scaling group to a new server added to that group?**

Comment: this can probably be achieved, but I believe you've got it wrong. autoscaling should alter the number of instances to accommodate the workload that you have not the other way around. You should have a fixed number of workers per instance and scale up when your workers cannot keep up and scale down when you have too many idle workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network may not up when you run this script, that is why aws cli is not responding and your script should call `exit 0` on success.  It is wrong to execute your script in rc.local since it is executed at the end of each runlevel.

I would call **aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --region us-east-1 --query AutoScalingInstances[].InstanceId --output text | wc -w** in your code to get the number of members i the auto scaling group.

> ## rc.local
>
> #
>
> ## This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
>
> ## Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
>
> ## value on error.

Comment: Good call...I'm going to include this with the startup script to launch my app